# Calculating decile in presto

Tags: sql, presto

I need to calculate deciles on sales data in presto and I'm using the below-mentioned query to get it.

`ceil((sum(sales) over(order by sales asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row )/sum(sales) over())*10) sales_c12_decile`

The problem I face with this chunk of code is that it throws decile value 11 for the maximum sales value.
This might affect the deciles for the lower sales values.

Can someone please let me know what am I missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is a problem with numeric precision.  The `ceil()` logic should be doing what you want; but your problem suggests a numeric precision issue.

One work-around is to adjust the calculation by adding a small offset:

```
ceil(sum(sales) over (order by sales asc rows) * 10.0 /
     (sum(sales) over () + 0.0001)
    ) as sales_c12_decile
```

This should prevent any rounding problems from affecting the decile amounts.